# shell-script で、バックアップを取りながらほどよく mkdir するには

Tags: shellscript, unix

shell-script で、ほどよくバックアップをとりながらディレクトリを作成したいです。

というのも、もし作成しようとしているディレクトリがすでに存在したならば、その名称の末尾に `.bk${N}` を付与して移動したのちに、このディレクトリを作成したいです。

そして、ここでいう `N` は、この作成しようとしているバックアップディレクトリ名称に対して、既存のディレクトリ名称と被らないような最小の自然数です。

こういったことは、わりとよくやりたくなるのではないかと思っているのですが、一般的にこれを実現する方法などはありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ループを回して未使用のディレクトリを見つけるスクリプトを書くのが一番簡単かと思います。

ただし、同じディレクトリに対して同時に実行してしまわないように注意してください。

```
$ cat bkdir.sh 
#!/bin/sh
for DIR; do # 全引数に対してループ
        DIR="${DIR%/}" # 末尾の / を除去する
        if test -e "$DIR"; then
                i=1
                while test -e "$DIR.bk$i"; do
                        i=$((i+1))
                done
                mv "$DIR" "$DIR.bk$i"
        fi
        mkdir -p "$DIR"
done
```

実行例

```
$ ./bkdir.sh /tmp/dirs/test1 /tmp/dirs/test2/
$ ./bkdir.sh /tmp/dirs/test1 /tmp/dirs/test2/
$ ./bkdir.sh /tmp/dirs/test1 /tmp/dirs/test2/
$ ./bkdir.sh /tmp/dirs/test1 /tmp/dirs/test2/
$ ./bkdir.sh /tmp/dirs/test1 /tmp/dirs/test2/
$ ls -1F /tmp/dirs
test1/
test1.bk1/
test1.bk2/
test1.bk3/
test1.bk4/
test2/
test2.bk1/
test2.bk2/
test2.bk3/
test2.bk4/
```